# Synchronous way to generated web service using WSDL for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, soap-client

I' ve a WSDl file , please tel me how to generate the SOAP Client using it?
i used SudzC website  to generate the web client , but its generating Asynchronous code for me. I need some solution which generates Synchronous Web client for me. Please let me know which web site or command line tool generates the code for me.

THank YOu.

Answer (score 2):

Synchronous calls to network services make for a *very* poor user experience on mobile devices. Learn to use the asynchronous callbacks--it's not that much more difficult.